# How to tunnel a docker X windows to a remote host?

Tags: docker, ssh-tunnel

when I am at work, with Ubuntu 14.04 (IP: a.b.c.d) and I want to execute a program (p.e. firefox) in a docker container and get the graphic output, I start a shell in the docker container and in this shell I execute:

`DISPLAY=a.b.c.d:0 firefox`

On the other hand, when I am at home and I need to run a program in the work-pc and get the output in the home-pc with private IP address (NATed), I connect with:

```
$ ssh -X work-pc
```

then I run the program in that shell and get the output locally.

Is there a way of redirecting the output of the docker container to home thru the "ssh -X" tunnel?

I know I could install an ssh server in the container, redirect a port in the work-pc to port 22 of the container, redirect a home-pc local port to that work-pc port (using ssh -L port:host:port work-pc) and connect from home-pc to the container with "ssh -X" to get the output at home, but I wonder if there is other way.

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, it's ssh server or VNC.

Answer (score 0):

I got something to work following the instructions at https://dzone.com/articles/docker-x11-client-via-ssh.

My docker-compose has:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  rhel:
    privileged: true
    build:
      context: /home/mpawlowsky/docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /tmp/.x11-unix:/tmp/.x11-unix
      - /home/mpawlowsky/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:rw
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - NET_RAW
    environment:
      - DISPLAY
    network_mode: host
```

I start the container and run in it:

```
$ docker-compose up -d
$ docker exec -it rhel /bin/bash
$ firefox
```